# .Net img src syntax

Tags: html, .net, visual-studio

I am new to .Net and Visual Studio. I have a link to a picture with a variabel:

```
<img src=\"[Logo]\"
```

I need to change that to a path:

http://www.page.com/images/emailpictures/logo.png

How can I change that? I tried the following:

```
<img src=\"http://www.page.com/images/emailpictures/logo.png\"
<img src=\"http://www.page.com/images/emailpictures/logo.png"
<img src="http://www.page.com/images/emailpictures/logo.png"
```

But nothing is working. How is the syntaxs of it?

Best Regards.

Update

```
<img src=\"[Logo]\" border=\"0\" style=\"vertical-align: top; font: bold 13px/23px Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif; color: #493728; width: 100px; height: 23px;\" width=\"100\" height=\"23\" alt=\"testpage.com | your local test planer\" /></a>\r\n
```

Comment: Are you intentionally omitting the closing `>` for the `img` tags?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The whole code line is there now.  Should the [] be there when I reference an url? Should the \[]\ be there when you reference a link to a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="http://www.page.com/images/emailpictures/logo.png" runat="server" />
```

Assuming you're using ASP.NET, it gets weird sometimes and requires you to place a runat in your link to work sometimes, try it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your last example should work as long as you close the  with a ">" character, although well-formed XML with a "/>" at the end is preferred:

```
<img src="http://www.page.com/images/emailpictures/logo.png" />
```

You said you have a variable, so I assume you're in C# instead of HTML, in which case you'll have to escape the quotes like so:

```
string s = "<img src=\"http://www.page.com/images/emailpictures/logo.png\" />";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually have to change it from a variable to a path. So I do not need [] right?